# Produce old style graphs and diagrams with gnuplot?

Tags: graphics, gnuplot

Hello fellow Stackoverflowers:

I am curious if it is possible to create a style or control the aestetic of the graphs and diagrams to look like they are from a turn-de-siclé book (talking about the 19th-20th centuries), that is, imitate the look of an etched graph. I have a simple diagram that I produced on inkscape that is a very very crude aproximation to what I am looking.

[image]

Could I produce something more "metal/wood engraving" on gnuplot? I have gnuplot 5.0.5.   Thank for your attention, I hope this is the right forum.

Answer (score 0):

Use gnuplot command `test` to see what fill patterns available.

[image: gnuplot test command output]

Modifying or adding custom fill pattern is extremely difficult in gnuplot, as far as I know. See this example for how to manipulate the fill pattern: [Gnuplot: how to fill a bar with both a color background and a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065288/gnuplot-how-to-fill-a-bar-with-both-a-color-background-and-a-pattern)